# Range of $ f(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) $

Tags: functions, inverse-function, elementary-functions

> Find the range of $ f(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) $

We already know that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ so to find the range of $f$ we solve $y=f(x)$ in terms of $x$ and we try to limit the values of $y$.

$y=f(x) \Rightarrow y=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) \Rightarrow e^y=x+\sqrt{x^2+1} \Rightarrow e^y-x=\sqrt{x^2+1}$

But we know that $\sqrt{x^2+1} > 0 \Rightarrow e^y-x>0 \Rightarrow e^y>x\quad (1)$

Then by squaring both sides we get $e^{2y}-2xe^y+x^2=x^2+1 \Rightarrow x=\dfrac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}$

We know that $x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \dfrac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}\in \mathbb{R}$ which does not provide any limitation for $y$.

Does $(1)$ provide any limitation for $y$? if not why?

I understand that $g(x)=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ has $\mathbb{R}$ as its domain and $g$ is essentially the inverse function of $f$ but I dont know how to formally show that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Not answering your questions near the bottom. But note that $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$ as $x\to-\infty$. And $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is unbounded as $x\to\infty$. So $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ has range $(0,\infty)$, which is the full domain of $\ln$. So the final range is the full range of $\ln$, which is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily evaluate
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
but also, with $x=-t$,
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln(-t+\sqrt{t^2+1})=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln\frac{1}{t+\sqrt{t^2+1}}=-\infty
$$
The intermediate value theorem ends the task.

---

Without calculus, one can find the inverse function: if $y=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$, then
\begin{align}
e^y&=x+\sqrt{x^2+1},
\\
e^{-y}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{x^2+1-x^2}=
\sqrt{x^2+1}-x
\end{align}
and so
$$
2x=e^{y}-e^{-y}
$$
which is usually written $x=\sinh y$.

Now this function is defined with no restriction on $y$:
$$
g(y)=\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}=\sinh y
$$
This precisely means that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I certainly agree with you but for a student who is not into limits yet how would you justify that?

Comment: @ChrisGalanis Added the calculus-free argument.

Comment: as I stated the calculus-free explanation provides the restriction $e^y>x$. Why doesnt this restriction restrict the values of $y$?

Comment: @ChrisGalanis And where's the problem? You can just conclude that if $y=f(x)$, then $e^y>x$, but this doesn't by itself limit the range of $y$, because this $y$ depends on $x$.

Comment: In order for this restriction to not restrict the values of $y$, we must conclude that this restriction holds for all real $y$. In fact if $x<0$ we get $e^y>0>x$ which holds for all real $y$. But in case $x>0$ we get $y>lnx$. How do we know that the latter holds for all real $y$

Comment: @ChrisGalanis Sorry, but I can't understand what your doubt is. It just happens that, if $y=f(x)$, then $x<e^y$. This is completely irrelevant as far as the range of $f$ is concerned.

Comment: @ChrisGalanis The fact that you're squaring is irrelevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of a function is the set of input or argument values for which the function is real and defined.
Solving
$$x+\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$$
it is true $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. The function has no undefined points nor domain constraints. Therefore, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.
For the range you should find the codomain=range. In fact if a function $f(x)$ is mapping $x\mapsto y$, then the inverse function of $f(x)$ maps $y$ back to $x$.

If

$$x=\ln \left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right), \quad x\leftrightarrow y$$

solving to $x$ we have

$$\ln \left(e^x\right)=\ln \left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)$$
hence for the propriety $\log _b\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=\log _b\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\quad \Rightarrow \quad f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$, we have

$$e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$$

After squaring

$$e^{2x}=y^2+2y\sqrt{y^2+1}+y^2+1$$
$$e^{2x}-1=\color{red}{2y^2+2y\sqrt{y^2+1}}=2y(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}) \tag{*}$$

Hence being $x=\ln \left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)\rightarrow y+\sqrt{y^2+1}=e^x$ we have

$$y=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\left(e^{2x}-1\right)$$
and the domain of this function (i.e. range) is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Range and domain are quite different things. The function $f(x)=x^2$ has domain $\mathbb{R}$, but its range is $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @egreg Then what is the range? A restriction of a function? The range of a function never studied at university.

Comment: @egreg Hi, excuse me always. Now my answer is correct? Thank you.